# R Shiny - Isolating a reactive expression that uses req() to check preconditions

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

The app below contains a `selectInput` with two options `iris` and `mtcars` and a header that displays the current selection.

- If the user selects `iris`, a DT of the corresponding dataset is rendered below the header.
- If the user selects `mtcars`, nothing is rendered below the header.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I store the selected dataset in a reactive expression, `sel_df`. The expression checks if the user has selected iris using `req(input$dataset=='iris')` before returning the corresponding dataset:

```
sel_df = reactive({

    req(input$dataset=='iris')

    iris
  })
```

`sel_df` is passed to `renderDT` which renders the datatable:

```
output$df = renderDT({

    sel_df()

  })
```

I then render some UI to display the current value of the selectInput using an h3 header, the datatable and a label for the datatable:

```
  output$tbl = renderUI({

    tagList(
      h3(paste0('Selected:', input$dataset)), # Header should be visible regardless of the value of input$dataset
      tags$label(class = 'control-label', style = if(!isTruthy(isolate(sel_df()))) 'display:none;', `for` = 'df', 'Data:'), # Label should only show if input$dataset == 'iris'
      DTOutput('df')
    )

  })
```

I would like the datatable and its label to only be visible if `sel_df` outputs a dataset. But due to the way the app is structured, this requires `output$tbl` (the `renderUI` above) to take a dependency on `sel_df`, so that the entire UI chunk disappears whenever `input$dataset == 'mtcars'`.

My desired output requires `output$tbl` to only take a dependency on `input$dataset`, so that the h3 header is always visible regardless of the value of `input$dataset`. To do this, I tried 'isolating' `sel_df` using `isolate`, but `output$tbl` still calls `sel_df` each time it's invalidated.

I am not sure where I am going wrong here. I think I may be using `isolate` incorrectly but I don't know why and was wondering if someone could shed some light.

Here is the app in full:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput('dataset', 'Dataset', c('iris', 'mtcars')),
  uiOutput('tbl')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  sel_df = reactive({

    req(input$dataset=='iris')

    iris
  })

  output$df = renderDT({

    sel_df()

  })

  output$tbl = renderUI({

    tagList(
      h3(paste0('Selected:', input$dataset)), # Header should be visible regardless of the value of input$dataset
      tags$label(class = 'control-label', style = if(!isTruthy(isolate(sel_df()))) 'display:none;', `for` = 'df', 'Data:'), # Label should only show if input$dataset == 'iris'
      DTOutput('df')
    )

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: " but output$tbl still calls sel_df each time it's invalidated." how do you track that,...with display mode = showcase?

Comment: I just inferred it from the fact that the `output$tbl` disappears entirely if `input$dataset != "iris"`, which would imply that `output$tbl` stops upon calling `sel_df`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`output$tbl` depends on `input$dataset`, so naturally it is called each time the value of `input$dataset` changes. `sel_df()` also depends on `input$dataset` and gets called whenever it changes. This is all how it is expected to be, I don't think your label is called because it depends on `sel_df()`.

However, please note that when `sel_df` is NULL, the `taglist()` call will also return NULL. This is because your `sel_df()` call *fails* silently when `input$dataset != "iris"`, and consequently `tagList` fails as well:

> If any of the given values is not truthy, the operation is stopped by raising a
>   "silent" exception (not logged by Shiny, nor displayed in the Shiny app's UI).

Try this:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  sel_df = reactive({
    if(input$dataset=='iris') {
      iris 
    } else {
      NULL
    }
  })
```

You will find that with mtcars, the `h3()` tag is shown, but the label is hidden as desired.

Comment: Yes, I understand that `req` causes `sel_df` to fail silently if `input$dataset != 'iris'` but how can I check for that in the IF statement that decides whether to display the label? I had used if/else initially but found `req` to be more convenient since `sel_df` is also used elsewhere in calls to other render functions and it saves me from having to write `req(sel_df())` in each of those calls.

Comment: Also, as I am checking for multiple conditions, I end up using nested if/elses which is not as readable as req.

Comment: You can't eat the cake and have the cake, I'm afraid ;-) `req` is in a way an equivalent of using `stopifnot` and this is how you should treat it! How about defining another reactive expression which checks whether `input$dataset == 'iris'` and sets a flag, similar to the `sel_df` definition in my response, without `req`?

Comment: That's true :) I just wanted to make sure there wasn't an easier way. I ended up using something like `sel_df <- reactive({ #calculate value1; if(#value1 does not meet condition1) return(NULL); #calculate value2; if(#value2 does not meet condition2) return(NULL); #more calculations})`. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use `req` in `sel_df()` you could use a `trycatch` in `renderDT` this addresses the problem mentioned by @January, of `tagsList` failing when you do not select iris.

You will also need to modify the if statement to use `is.null` rather, as I use this as the default `return` value in the `trycatch`.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput('dataset', 'Dataset', c('iris', 'mtcars')),
  uiOutput('tbl')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  sel_df = reactive({
    req(input$dataset=='iris')
    iris
  })

  output$df = renderDT({

    out <- tryCatch(sel_df(), error = function(e) NULL)
    return(out)

  })

  output$tbl = renderUI({

    tagList(
      tags$h3(paste0('Selected:', input$dataset)), # Header should be visible regardless of the value of input$dataset
      tags$label(class = 'control-label', style = if(is.null('df')) 'display:none;', `for` = 'df', 'Data:'), # Label should only show if input$dataset == 'iris'
      DTOutput('df')
    )

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you @RK1, I didn't think to use tryCatch like that, I have upvoted.